# Is msvcr90.dll timestamped?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, digital-certificate

When looking at the digital certifcate of msvcr90.dll in the Visual Studio 2008 'redist' folder, the validity period is set from 8/23/2007 to 2/23/2009.

However, after searching online i found that [as long as the dll is timestamped within the specified period, this should not be a problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx).

Is there a way i can check if the dll is timestamped? Or do i have an old version of the dll for some reason?

Thanks in Advance!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the time stamp by:

1. Find the file in explorer.
2. Right click on it and select the Properties menu item.
3. Select the Digital Signatures tab and view the timestamp.

It looks like this:

[image]